# Customise Ubuntu Dock like Unity Launcher Desktop 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, dock, ubuntu-dock

I have recently upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04 desktop.

In 16.04 I was able to add to the right-click behaviour of icons in the launcher - eg have a simple icon in the launcher bar, right click to show a list of all libreoffice programs and choose the one I wanted. Also I added programs such as FreeFileSync, Disk, gParted to the right-click list on the nautilus icon.

Is it possible to do this within the GNOME environment?  If not then is there an alternative?

I've already looked at Docky, not sure that it does all I need it to...

Comment: Thanks guys, my searches didn't bring up that post!